# introduction books for Dynamic systems of discrete Schrodinger operator for beginner

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, elliptic-pde, hyperbolic-dynamics, schrodinger-operators

In this semester, I study in a class of dynamic system. recently the French professor turn to the dynamic system of discrete operator. I find it is difficult to find a book in English. (I have found many references written by  french, however I can not read French.)

are there any good reference of books, or papers in this direction especially for beginners. I like to know this area through reading classical papers. For an example, I know that Furstenberg's a series of fundamental  papers for Lyapunov exponent are very good ones for the beginners to study Lyapunov exponent. I have to say, to read Furstenberg's is very enjoyable experience. Whether  there are some papers of Schrodinger operator which are very classical deserve to read many times for beginners?

Any comments and reference will be greatly appreciated.